# Професія дресирувати тварин

Tags: вибір-слова

Професія дресирувати тварин - це *дресувальник* / *дресирувальник* / *приборкувач* або інші варіанти?

Я маю на увазі працівника цирку.

Comment: Перепрошую, але «[дрес**и**рува́ти](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24937&page=830)», а не «дрес**е**рува́ти».

Comment: Вас цікавить взагалі суфікс `-ир-` чи одне конкретне слово? Від цього можуть сильно залежати відповіді. Чи переглядали ви якісь варіанти у словниках? Чим вони не подобаються?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Серед названих варіантів «**[дресирува́льник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24936&page=830)**» і «**[прибо́ркувач](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryborkuvach)**» є нормативними словами.

«Дресувальник» у словниках відсутнє. І це не дивно, адже ми *дресируємо*, а не *дресуємо*. Хоча теоретично слова «дресувати», «дресувальник» могли б існувати в мові (тим більше, маємо слово «[дресу́ра](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=201512&page=831)»), але на практиці слова «дресувати» і «дресувальник», здається, не є нормативними.

«Дресирувальник» і «приборкувач» відрізняються за змістом:

- *Приборкувач* — це той, хто *[приборкує](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryborkuvaty)*, тобто втихомирює, усмиряє (в широкому значенні — підкоряє своїй волі). Приборкувач може бути не лише в цирку, наприклад, Моріс Джеральд з [роману «Вершник без голови» Майна Ріда](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_(%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)) займався тим, що ловив і приборкував диких мустангів (хоч формально його приборкувачем не називали). З іншого боку, не кожного, хто працює в цирку з тваринами, можна назвати приборкувачем; наприклад, [Куклачова](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (відомого клоуна і дресирувальника домашніх кішок) не можна назвати приборкувачем — бо кішки вже домашні тварини (так само, як не можна назвати приборкувачами циркових артистів, що показують виконання вправ собаками, козами й іншими свійськими тваринами, що були приборкані багато тисяч років тому).

  В широкому сенсі (переносному) приборкуванням можна назвати будь-яке підкорення своїй волі — не лише диких тварин, а й людей, речей, домашніх тварин. Але це значення переносне; пряме — це саме підкорення диких тварин.
- *Дресирувальник* — це той, хто *[дресирує](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=24937&page=830)*, тобто навчає тварин якимсь вправам. Дресирувати можна не лише в цирку; наприклад, можна дресирувати службових собак на виконання певної роботи (пошук наркотиків, взяття сліду, допомогу сліпим), можна дресирувати домашніх тварин на виконання певних команд («апорт», «сидіти», «голос»). На початкових етепах розвитку цирку, мабуть, не кожен, хто демонстрував номери з тваринами, був дресирувальником; адже якщо тварина насправді не навчена або взагалі виконує скоріше роль декору (наприклад, людина входить в клітку з тиграми, демонструючи свою відвагу, або жене ведмежат по сцені батогами), це навряд можна назвати дресируванням; але в сучасних цирках, мабуть, люде займаються здебільшого дресируванням, а не просто підкоренням чи демонстацією дивних істот.

  В широкому сенсі дресируванням можуть називати і навчання людини. Це робиться або задля підкреслення низькорівньового характеру навчання (людина, як тварина, примітивно реагує на певні стимули, не усвідомлюючи всього своїм мозком), або задля іронічного ефекту.

Те, як правильно називати сучасних артистів цирку, що працюють з тваринами, мабуть, варто подивитися в переліку професій. Формально — не кожен цирковий номер з тваринами має відношення до приборкування (наприклад, номери зі свійськими тваринами не мають), але й не кожен цирковий номер з тваринами має відношення до дресирування (хоча в сучасному цирку такі номери, мабуть, рідкість).

[Класифікатор професій від 1998-05-14](http://www.dcz.gov.ua/lviv/doccatalog/document?id=3994) (можливо, не найновіший):

> 3474 | артист-дресирувальник тварин
>   3474 | артист-дресирувальник хижих звірів
>   <…>
>   3474 | приборкувач диких тварин

Comment: «Дресура» та «дресирувати» – це настільки німецькі слова, що аж свистять. Німецьким суфіксом _-ur_ утворюються іменники, суфіксом _-ir-_ дієслова. Як правило, українська уникає цього німецького суфіксу _-ір-_, дивно, що він є в слові «дресирувати», звучить як росіянізм.

Comment: _Ми дресируємо, а не дресуємо_ - А от Агатангел Кримський з вами [не згоден](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=дрессировать&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on). І ось ще цікаве: [_муштрувальник, муштрій_](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=дрессировщик&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on).

Comment: @YellowSky, прийнято. Я написав з точки зору сучасних академічних словників. Я бачив, що в Інтернеті «дресувати» пишуть і мені самому після N-го вживання «дресирувати» почало здаватись, що це росіянізм.

Comment: @YellowSky, буду радий, якщо Ви напишете окрему відповідь на захист інших варіантів.

Comment: Обов’язково напишу. Я просто думав, що ви це додасте до вашої відповіді. От мені цікаво, якщо я на якесь питання дам дві окремі відповіді з різних точок зору, кожна з яких виключає иншу, як на це подивиться товариство? Чи це буде відповідати загальній етиці SE? Бо ви ж розумієте, що питання бувають такі, що одностайної думки годі й скласти.

Comment: Виправте ***«Дресувальник»** і «приборкувач» відрізняються за змістом*. Платформа не дозволяе мені змінювати менше 6 символів ((

Comment: Була в мене ідея полізти у класифікатор професій, та я завагався.